# Having trouble proving index sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I have this question: 
For $i \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ with $i \ge 1$, let $A_{i} = [0, 1-\frac{1}{i}].$

Part a.) asks to Find $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}}A_{i}$ and $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}}A_{i}$.

Which I computed to find $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}}A_{i} = [0,1)$ and $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}}A_{i} = \{0\}$.

Now part b.) is asking to prove that part a.)'s answers to be correct. Now I am stuck here, because the book doesn't seem to explain it very well. Can someone help me on how I go by proving these two? 
I started the proof like so:

First we show that $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}}A_{i} = [0,1)$. Let $n \in \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}} A_{i}$...

Not sure if I started off correctly, therefore, I hope some can help me out getting on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part a), first consider $x\in\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^+} \left[0,1-\frac{1}{i}\right]$, then, by definition of union, there exists $i\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $x\in \left[ 0,1-\frac{1}{i}\right]\subseteq[0,1)$ because for all $i$ holds that $1-\frac{1}{i}<1$. We have the first contention.
Then, consider $x\in [0,1)$, by definition, $0\leq x<1$, then, by the Archimedean property, there exists $i\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $0\leq x < 1-\frac{1}{i}<1$. With this, $x\in \left[0,1-\frac{1}{i}\right]\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^+} \left[0,1-\frac{1}{i}\right]$. Is it clear for you? The second part is totally analogous. Can you do it?

Comment: I am starting to understand it, I'll try and finish it, and if I get stuck, I'll ask away. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, fine. Only coment here if you can't do the second part.